# tkinter Label updating but not correctly

Tags: python, tkinter, label

Using Python 3.5. I have a `tkinter` form. The user clicks a button to import many files into a `Listbox`. Another button loops thru the files and reads and extracts data from them.

I have a `Label` on the form that indicates the status of the loop. The status, for the most part, works as expected except that extra characters are added on the end. I'm not sure where the characters come from. I also `print()` the same content as the `Label` back to the screen and the `print()` displays exactly what it should.

My question is why is my `Label` not displaying the correct string?

My code, greatly shortened:

```
class tk_new_db:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master  # sets 'root' to the instance variable 'master'
        self.var_text_2 = StringVar()
        self.var_text_2.set('STATUS: Active')
        self.label_6 = Label(master, textvariable=self.var_text_2,
                             font=self.font_10)
        self.label_6.grid(row=15, sticky=W, padx=15)

    def execute_main(self):  # extract data from files
        file_num = 0
        nf = len(self.listbox_1.get(0, END))
        for fr in li:
            file_num += 1
            print('STATUS: Extracting Loads from File '
                  '{} in {}'.format(file_num, nf))
            self.var_text_2.set('STATUS: Extracting Loads from File '
                                '{} in {}'.format(file_num, nf))
            self.master.update_idletasks()
```

The `print()` is writing the following:
`STATUS: Extracting Loads from File 1 in 5`

The `Label` is writing the following:
`STATUS: Extracting Loads from File 1 in 5 nce...`

It always adds `' nce...'` on the Form.

EDIT:

I do use `self.var_text_2` earlier in the program. The `' nce...'` looks like it is a fragment of the previous string. I've since tried resetting the variable in two different ways, but I'm still getting the same result.

```
    self.var_text_2.set('STATUS: Checking .F06 Files for Convergence...')
    self.master.update_idletasks()
    self.var_text_2.__del__()

    self.var_text_2.set('STATUS: Checking .F06 Files for Convergence...')
    self.master.update_idletasks()
    self.var_text_2.set('')
```

How do you properly delete the `StringVar()` for reuse?

Comment: Perhaps there was some text before that ended with 'nce'. You can try `self.master.update_idletasks()` after the change of the label text and see if that fixes.

Comment: You've shortened your code too much. There's nothing in it to account for what you say is happening. Please [edit] your question and replace the code with a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: There is no special method to clear a `StringVar`. Every time you call its `set()` method, the value passed as an argument entirely replaces whatever value it had previously (and the text of any `Label` instances that had it set as their `textvariable` option will automatically be updated). Variable classes like `StringVar` all have a `trace()` method — which is (poorly) explained [here](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm) — that you might be able to use to discover what is going on by arranging for something to be called every time its value is changed.

Comment: Everywhere I've read recommends NOT using `update()`, but, it actually makes the Label update correctly. I don't know why `update_idletasks()` isn't working properly. My situation seems basic enough.

Comment: Is this a multithreaded program?  Most GUIs, and I think this includes tk, are not threadsafe.  You can only change the state of a widget from the main thread.  Some pretty strange things can happen if you try.

Comment: Another thing to look at is re-painting.  If your replace a long label text with a short one, what causes a repaint of the background?  I have seen situations where an error in the layout code caused a problem like this; if there's a mistake in parent-child relationships, for example, the repaint mechanism can get messed up.

Comment: If calling `update()` instead of `update_idletasks()` works for you, then use it. The warnings about not using the former seem mostly to be about not doing so in an event callback or function called from one.

Comment: please provide a _complete_ working example. Read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

The only explanation I can think of is that you're stacking labels on top of each other in the same row and column, so when you add a long string that ends in "nce..." and later update the screen by adding a shorter label in the same grid cell, the trailing text of the longer label underneath is showing through.

The reasons I draw this conclusion are:

1. this is a common mistake I've seen several times
2. there are no bugs in tkinter that would cause this
3. there is nothing in the code that you've shown that could possibly add "nce..." to the end of the string
4. the fact that  you use `sticky="w"` rather than `sticky="ew"`, which will cause a shorter label to not completely overlay a longer label if placed in the same row and column

Answer (score 0):

I think I can explain.  Root.mainloop repeatedly calls root.update.  Root.update executes tasks on the 'main' event queue.  In brief, it only executes idletasks when the event queue is empty *after* checking for file events (on non-Windows), window-gui events, and timer events.  Idletasks, which are not well documented but seem to primarily be screen update tasks, are never added to the main event queue.  It is therefore possible that idletasks will remain undone indefinitely.  Root.update_idletasks exists to force execution of idletasks anyway.

When mainloop is running, calling update within a task run by update is usually unnecessary and possibly worse.  It is something only for adventurous experts.  Hence the warnings you have read (which assume that you are running mainloop).

When mainloop is not running and update is not being called repeatedly, either because you never called mainloop or because you block it with a long running loop, then you likely must call update yourself.  What you seem to have discovered is that part of completely handling a StringVar update is a main event and not just an idletask.

I sympathize with your desire to do repeated tasks with a for loop, but doing so currently means taking responsibility for event handling yourself.  I hope in the future that it will be possible to have 'async for' (new in 3.5) interoperate with Tk.mainloop, but it is not as easy as I hoped.

In the meanwhile, you could put the body of the for loop into a callback and loop with root.after.