# overlapping statuses using tkinter module

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to work on GUI using tkinter module. I created label with random greetings generator. However,they are overlapping with previous generated labels.This is the code:

```
import tkinter
import random

window = tkinter.Tk()
# to rename the title of the window
window.title("GUI")

window.geometry("500x500")

#defining Functions
def search_greetings():
    phrases = ["Hallo ", "Hoi ", "Greetings "]
    name = str(entry1.get())
    text = ".Please enter your search term below."
    return phrases[random.randint(0, 2)] + name + text

def search_display():
    greeting = search_greetings()
    # This creates the text field
    greeting_display = tkinter.Label(window,text = search_greetings())
    greeting_display.grid(row=6,column=1)
    search_box = tkinter.Entry()
    search_box.grid(row=7)


# pack is used to show the object in the window
label = tkinter.Label(window, text = "Hello World! Welcome to my app")
label.grid(row = 0)

# creating 2 text labels and input labels

tkinter.Label(window, text = "Username").grid(row = 2) # this is placed in 1 0
# 'Entry' is used to display the input-field
entry1 = tkinter.Entry()
entry1.grid(row = 2, column = 1) # this is placed in 1 1

tkinter.Label(window, text = "Password").grid(row = 3) # this is placed in 2 0
tkinter.Entry().grid(row = 3, column = 1) # this is placed in 2 1

# 'Checkbutton' is used to create the check buttons
tkinter.Checkbutton(window, text = "Keep Me Logged In").grid(columnspan = 2) # 'columnspan' tells to take the width of 2 columns
                                                                             # you can also use 'rowspan' in the similar manner


# Submit button
button = tkinter.Button(text = "Submit",command = search_display).grid(row = 5)     

window.mainloop()
```

It is returning the labels like below:
Greetings 1234.Please enter your search term below.

G Hallo ashita.Please enter your search term below.v.

G Hallo ashita.Please enter your search term below..v.

Please check the error in the code.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you are making a new Label every time. You can edit a Label's text like so:

```
mylabel = tkinter.Label(root, text="First!")
mylabel["text"] = "Second!"
```

This will display "Second!" (after being packed). You can even change the text after the Label is packed.

Comment: I am using search_display function to generate the displays. Do I need to change anything in this function?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38985226/tkinter-label-updating-but-not-correctly this is kind of my issue

Comment: You would either:
- Not want to generate a new label every time you call search_display. (instead change the text in the label that already exists, as mentioned in my answer above)
- Destroy the previously generated label (if there is one) and generate a new one.